# Correct way to manage redis connections in django

Tags: python, django, database, redis, database-connection

I have a django project that uses a redis (just one db in redis).

Currently I do this:

In my settings.py file, I have:

```
from redis import Redis
REDIS_CONNECTION = Redis()
```

Anytime I want to call this connection (on my many views.py file in different apps in the project) I do it this way:

```
from django.conf import settings
settings.REDIS_CONNECTION.lpush("testlist", "hello")
```

Is there a problem with this approach? I do not want to keep creating new connections to redis if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the official package documentation:

> **Behind the scenes, redis-py uses a connection pool to manage connections to a Redis server. By default, each Redis instance you create will in turn create its own connection pool**. You can override this behavior and use an existing connection pool by passing an already created connection pool instance to the connection_pool argument of the Redis class. You may choose to do this in order to implement client side sharding or have finer grain control of how connections are managed.

(see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/)

If you want to use a centralized pool, instantiate one in a centralized place and every time you create a new instance pass it that new instance:

```
pool = ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
r = Redis(connection_pool=pool)
```

In my modest opinion (not an expert) I would keep using the default way you've been working with and fallback to this approach **only** when you face performance issues.

Eager optimization can be worse than no optimization IMO.